# Login with one parameter

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I want to make a login in Laravel that receives only one parameter, i.e. has a simple form that receives one input, and based on that  input, the user is authenticated. If user is admin, it will redirect to `/adminpage`, else if the user is a regular user it redirects to `/homepage`.

I want to use a custom table, model, and controller. I searched the internet but could not find a solution.

**EDIT**
I have form like this:

```
<form action="someroute" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="rf_id">
<input type="submit" value="login">
</form>
```

My migration is:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('lastname');
            $table->string('workid');
            $table->boolean('isAdmin')->default(False);
            $table->string('rf_id');//
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Now i need controller that handle this.
So base on rf_id, controller needs to fin user and thec check his role.
I try this but don't work:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class TestController extends Controller
{


    public function index(){
        return view('singin');
    }

    public function login(Request $request){

        $credentials = $request->only('rf_id');

        if(Auth::attempt($credentials)){
             //we need to know who is logging in
             return $this->filterAndRedirect(Auth::user());
         }
         return "there is no user with that rfid";
     }

     private function filterAndRedirect(User $user){
       //the function to take care of the routing
       if($user->isAdmin){
          # return redirect('/homepage');
          return "This is admin";

       }
       else{
          # return redirect('/adminpage');
          return "This is worker";

     }

}
}
```

Comment: You can define types of users and set them in your table.Then make a middelware that checks the user type if the user is admin route it to admin section and if a user is normal user route them to different route

Comment: yes you need custom model table and all things.

Comment: can you provide what have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it;

- First of all you have to add the table column in your migration file for the user-type and the login parameter.Check below for migration docs
- Next is the page where you have the form, I don't know what your parameter is so I'll just call it 'param'. I am assuming you know how to create and submit forms with laravel so I won't put the code here.
- Now the interesting part, the controllers:

This is how my user creation in the RegisterController would look;

**Note that I'm using the standard laravel auth controllers**

```
public function createStandardUser(Request $request){
    //function to add the Standard user
    $user = User::create([
    'name' => $request['name'],
    'email' => $request['email'],
    'param' => $request['login-param'],
    'user-type' => 'standard'//the user type
    ]);

    Auth::login($user);//Explicitly starts a new session for the user 
    return redirect('/homepage');
}
```

If you are gonna have a different form for the Admin registration the function to add the admin user will roughly be the same;

```
public function createAdminUser(Request $request){
     //function to add the Admin user
     $user = User::create([
     'name' => $request['name'],
     'email' => $request['email'],
     'param' => $request['login-param'],
     'user-type' => 'admin'//the user type
    ]);

    Auth::login($user);//Explicitly starts a new session for the user
    return redirect('/adminpage');
}
```

- The last part would be the LoginController where you can use the `attempt()` function to authenticate the user and start a new session for them using your single parameter.

You will have these functions

```
public function login(Request $request){

   if(Auth::attempt(['login-param' => $request->get('login-param'])){
        //we need to know who is logging in
        return $this->filterAndRedirect(Auth::user());
    }
}

private function filterAndRedirect(User $user){
  //the function to take care of the routing
  if($user->user-type == 'standard'){
      return redirect('/homepage');

  }else if($user->user-type == 'admin'){
      return redirect('/adminpage');
  } 
}
```

The Relevant Documentation:[Database Migration Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations), [Laravel Authentication Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication)

*Suggestion:If I were you I would use Roles/Permissions as opposed to using a table row in your DB, I think its more robust. Check out this library it is well documented and gets updated* ->[Laravel Permission By Spatie](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission)

EDIT:**This answer assumes you are using the standard User model and Authentication Controllers because thats the whole point of using a framework isn't it?**